# Use Conditional Variational Autoencoder for Regression (CVAE)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying to implement a Conditional VAE for a regression problem, my dataset it's composed of images and a continuous value for each one.
I'm starting from this example [CVAE on mnist dataset](https://github.com/nnormandin/Conditional_VAE/blob/master/Conditional_VAE.ipynb) that is used for a classification problem, so what changes I have to made in order to deal with continuous values?

I think that if I simply concatenate the img (my data) with the single regression value and give it as input for the encoder and the decoder I would not treat the problem properly or am I wrong?

My final goal is to give a regression value to the model and generate an image.

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate as concat
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from scipy.misc import imsave
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
%pylab inline

(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train.astype('float32') / 255.
X_test = X_test.astype('float32') / 255.

n_pixels = np.prod(X_train.shape[1:])
X_train = X_train.reshape((len(X_train), n_pixels))
X_test = X_test.reshape((len(X_test), n_pixels))

y_train = to_categorical(Y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(Y_test)

n_z = 2 # latent space size
encoder_dim1 = 512 # dim of encoder hidden layer
decoder_dim = 512 # dim of decoder hidden layer
decoder_out_dim = 784 # dim of decoder output layer
activ = 'relu'
optim = Adam(lr=0.001)


n_x = X_train.shape[1]
n_y = y_train.shape[1]


n_epoch = 50

X = Input(shape=(n_x,))
label = Input(shape=(n_y,))

inputs = concat([X, label])

encoder_h = Dense(encoder_dim1, activation=activ)(inputs)
mu = Dense(n_z, activation='linear')(encoder_h)
l_sigma = Dense(n_z, activation='linear')(encoder_h)

def sample_z(args):
    mu, l_sigma = args
    eps = K.random_normal(shape=(m, n_z), mean=0., stddev=1.)
    return mu + K.exp(l_sigma / 2) * eps


# Sampling latent space
z = Lambda(sample_z, output_shape = (n_z, ))([mu, l_sigma])


z = Lambda(sample_z, output_shape = (n_z, ))([mu, l_sigma])

# merge latent space with label
zc = concat([z, label])

decoder_hidden = Dense(decoder_dim, activation=activ)
decoder_out = Dense(decoder_out_dim, activation='sigmoid')
h_p = decoder_hidden(zc)
outputs = decoder_out(h_p)

def vae_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    recon = K.sum(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
    kl = 0.5 * K.sum(K.exp(l_sigma) + K.square(mu) - 1. - l_sigma, axis=-1)
    return recon + kl

def KL_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return(0.5 * K.sum(K.exp(l_sigma) + K.square(mu) - 1. - l_sigma, axis=1))

def recon_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sum(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)

cvae = Model([X, label], outputs)
encoder = Model([X, label], mu)

d_in = Input(shape=(n_z+n_y,))
d_h = decoder_hidden(d_in)
d_out = decoder_out(d_h)
decoder = Model(d_in, d_out)

cvae.compile(optimizer=optim, loss=vae_loss, metrics = [KL_loss, recon_loss])


# compile and fit
cvae_hist = cvae.fit([X_train, y_train], X_train, verbose = 1, batch_size=m, epochs=n_epoch,
                            validation_data = ([X_test, y_test], X_test),
                            callbacks = [EarlyStopping(patience = 5)])

plt.imshow(X_train[0].reshape(28, 28), cmap = plt.cm.gray), axis('off')
plt.show()

print(Y_train[0])

encoded_X0 = encoder.predict([X_train[0].reshape((1, 784)), y_train[0].reshape((1, 10))])
print(encoded_X0)

z_train = encoder.predict([X_train, y_train])
encodings= np.asarray(z_train)
encodings = encodings.reshape(X_train.shape[0], n_z)
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
plt.scatter(encodings[:, 0], encodings[:, 1], c=Y_train, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.show()

def construct_numvec(digit, z = None):
    out = np.zeros((1, n_z + n_y))
    out[:, digit + n_z] = 1.
    if z is None:
        return(out)
    else:
        for i in range(len(z)):
            out[:,i] = z[i]
        return(out)
    
sample_3 = construct_numvec(3)
print(sample_3)

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))
plt.imshow(decoder.predict(sample_3).reshape(28,28), cmap = plt.cm.gray), axis('off')
plt.show()

dig = 3
sides = 8
max_z = 1.5

img_it = 0
for i in range(0, sides):
    z1 = (((i / (sides-1)) * max_z)*2) - max_z
    for j in range(0, sides):
        z2 = (((j / (sides-1)) * max_z)*2) - max_z
        z_ = [z1, z2]
        vec = construct_numvec(dig, z_)
        decoded = decoder.predict(vec)
        subplot(sides, sides, 1 + img_it)
        img_it +=1
        plt.imshow(decoded.reshape(28, 28), cmap = plt.cm.gray), axis('off')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=.2)
plt.show()

dig = 2
sides = 8
max_z = 1.5

img_it = 0
for i in range(0, sides):
    z1 = (((i / (sides-1)) * max_z)*2) - max_z
    for j in range(0, sides):
        z2 = (((j / (sides-1)) * max_z)*2) - max_z
        z_ = [z1, z2]
        vec = construct_numvec(dig, z_)
        decoded = decoder.predict(vec)
        subplot(sides, sides, 1 + img_it)
        img_it +=1
        plt.imshow(decoded.reshape(28, 28), cmap = plt.cm.gray), axis('off')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=.2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't think using one continues value is a good idea. Why don't you want to use one-hot instead?

Comment: I think use one-hot would not make sense for the regression because I would have multiple different and unrelated classes for each of the continues values (ie 0.34, 0.35, 0.38...) rather than having a correlation between the data.