# Defining loss function for autoencoder in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

I am trying to create autoencoder (CVAE) on similar lines like one given here: [Use Conditional Variational Autoencoder for Regression (CVAE)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65508300/11638153). However, in `vae_loss()` and in `KL_loss()`, different variables (`l_sigma`, `mu`) are used than what these functions take in. Running the code like this gives error `TypeError missing 2 required positional arguments` My question is what is correct way to pass the required variables, in this case 4 -  `l_sigma`, `mu`, `y_true`, `y_pred`, to the loss functions through `cvae.compile()` and `cvae.fit()` ? There seems another way https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Advanced-Deep-Learning-with-Keras/blob/master/chapter8-vae/cvae-cnn-mnist-8.2.1.py#L267 to define the loss function giving the required 4 variables. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To add hyperparameters to a custom loss function using `Tensorflow` you have to create a wrapper function that takes the hyperparameters, so you can try define your custom loss function as follow:

```py
def vae_loss_with_hyperparameters(l_sigma, mu):
    def vae_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        recon = K.sum(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
        kl = 0.5 * K.sum(K.exp(l_sigma) + K.square(mu) - 1. - l_sigma, axis=-1)
        return recon + kl
    return vae_loss
```

After, you can call the `compile()` method like that:   `cvae.compile(loss=vae_loss_with_hyperparameters(l_sigma=..., mu=...))`

Let me know if it works.

Comment: If you look at the code in first link, variables `l_sigma`, `mu`, are output of encoder network.